# Move multiples files at once with dialogue

Tags: c#

I want to move multiple files from different directories at once with a move files dialogue. For this I found `FileSystem.MoveFile`. But it only works with single files, one by one, not with multiple files under one dialogue.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You can write an app for that

Comment: @TheGeneral ?....

Comment: You can use MoveDirectory to move entire directory in one go

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I want to move single files from different directories.

Comment: .net doesn't have anything inbuilt for this. You can implement your own solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

I am assuming you have the files you wanna move in a List.

```
foreach(var file in Files)
{

FileSystem.MoveFile(sourcePath, destPath);

}
```

Comment: This is obvious. It is about having one dialogue for multiple files with two progress bars, not one window pop up after the other to move a single file each.

Comment: @FabienBiller: Then the only approach would be to Zip all the files into one and move to destination and unzip. Otherwise you've to write one on your own.